# Find Date of last Sunday From Current Date

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I want to find the date of last Sunday from Now. I have looked into NSDateComponents but Nothing worked right for me. 
Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    int weekday = [comps weekday];
    NSLog(@"the wee %d",weekday);
    NSDate *lastSunday = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:-3600*24*(weekday-1)];
    NSLog(@"nsdar %@",newDate);
```

this gives you the last sunday in `NSDate` format.. hope this helps.

Comment: N.B. adding a multiple of 24 hours doesn't necessarily give you the same **time** on a different day, if you go across a daylight savings changeover. If you only care about the date (i.e. year, month, day) then this is fine, but if you do care about the time, you should use `NSCalendar`'s `components:fromDate:` and `dateFromComponents:` to get the year, month, and day components and add (weekday-1) to the day.

Answer (score -1):

Get the past seven days from the current date. Iterate through it to find a date which is sunday . Not an optimized solution. but it will work.

Comment: Iterate through what? weekday value?

Comment: the past seven dates. @ankit  answer is much better.